# GetView not called on notifyDataSetChanged, ListView is stuck

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem, I have created custom adapter with custom filtering on Contact object in Contacts app, it filters names of contacts just fine and list of filteredContacts is saved properly. The problem is that when I type anything in searchView, the number of found rows is correct but informations about found rows are not correct. The problem seems to be about getView function in adapter, it is not called when it should. For example if i have three contacts: "abc", "aaa", "aba" and they are shown at the beggining in this order from top to bottom, then if I type "ab" in searchView then it finds 2 rows but they are still the same as at the beggining, they should be "abc" and "aba" but they are "abc" and "aaa". The first ever view created by adapter seems to be stuck for some reason.

My activity class:

```
package com.example.androidlab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AllContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter;

    ListView listView;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_contacts);

        FloatingActionButton addContact = findViewById(R.id.newContact);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.allContactsList);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchContacts);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.tanay.thunderbird.contacts", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("contacts", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Contact>>() {
        }.getType();
        contacts = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if (contacts == null) {
            contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (contacts.size() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, contacts);
        listView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditContactActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteID", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                contactsAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                contactsAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });

        addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewContactActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

My adapter class:

```
package com.example.androidlab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    List<Contact> contacts;
    List<Contact> filteredContacts;
    ContactFilter mFilter = new ContactFilter();
    String filterString;

    ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contacts = contacts;
        filteredContacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(contacts.size() != filteredContacts.size() || filterString != null)
        {
            return filteredContacts.size();
        }
        else {
            filteredContacts = contacts;
            return contacts.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return contacts.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name;
        TextView phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(AllContactsActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_contacts, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageOfContact);
                holder.phoneNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

                Contact contact;

                if(filteredContacts.size() != contacts.size()) contact = filteredContacts.get(position);
                else contact = contacts.get(position);

                if (contact.getAvatar() == null) {
                    if (contact.getGender() == true)
                        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_man);
                    else holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_woman);
                } else {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(contact.getAvatar(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                }
                holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
                holder.phoneNumber.setText(String.valueOf(contact.getPhoneNumber()));
            }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ContactFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<Contact> list = contacts;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<Contact> nList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if(contacts.get(i).getName().contains(filterString)) nList.add(contacts.get(i));
            }

            results.values = nList;
            results.count = nList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredContacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I got rid of if(contentView == null) in getView function and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

The check for `convertView == null` should only handle the inflation of your `View` and the creation of a new `ViewHolder` the rest of you `getView` code should always run.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder holder; 

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_contacts, null);
        // attach a new holder to the inflated view
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else { 
        // get an existing holder from the existing view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    } 

    // update your holder here:
    // e.g. holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
    
    return convertView; 
}
```